# Disable touch screen Ubuntu 20.04 Huawei matebook pro

Tags: touchscreen, wacom

I'm trying to disable the touch screen on my huawei matebook x pro laptop, due to a crack in the screen corner.
This makes my cursor go crazy, with random mouse clicks where the crack is.

I've tried:

`xinput --list`

where I get:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA2393:00 06CB:19AC                     id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA1D31:00 06CB:CD48 Mouse               id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA1D31:00 06CB:CD48 Touchpad            id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Camera: HD Camera                      id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Huawei WMI hotkeys                        id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I can't see anything related to touch screen here.

I've also tried to disable the drivers by uncommenting in

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf`

```
# Some of the below input classes appear 3x times, once for each of
# "tablet", "touchscreen", and "touchpad" to ensure that the Wacom
# driver is not accidentally bound to other types of hardware that
# Wacom has made which are not handled by the wacom driver (e.g the
# Wacom Bluetooth Keyboard)
#
# https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/294/

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom USB tablet class"
        MatchUSBID "056a:*"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTablet "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

#Section "InputClass"
#        Identifier "Wacom USB touchscreen class"
#        MatchUSBID "056a:*"
#        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
#        MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
#        Driver "wacom"
#EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom USB touchpad class"
        MatchUSBID "056a:*"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTouchpad "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom tablet class"
        MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTablet "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

#Section "InputClass"
#       Identifier "Wacom touchscreen class"
#       MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
#       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
#       MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
#       Driver "wacom"
#EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom touchpad class"
        MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTouchpad "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Serial Wacom devices should always be one of tablet, touchscreen, or
# touchpad so we can safely get away with just one match section in
# these cases
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom PnP device class"
        MatchPnPID "WACf*|WCOM*|WACM*|FUJ02e5|FUJ02e7|FUJ02e9"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom serial class"
        MatchProduct "Serial Wacom Tablet"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom serial class identifiers"
        MatchProduct "WACf|FUJ02e5|FUJ02e7|FUJ02e9"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Hanwang tablets
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Hanwang class"
        MatchProduct "Hanwang"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Waltop tablets
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Waltop class"
        MatchProduct "WALTOP"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# N-Trig Duosense Electromagnetic Digitizer
#Section "InputClass"
#       Identifier "Wacom N-Trig class"
#       MatchProduct "HID 1b96:0001|N-Trig Pen|N-Trig DuoSense"
#       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
#       Driver "wacom"
#       Option "Button2" "3"
#EndSection

# Dell Canvas 27 (touch part is an Advanced Silicon, pen part a Wacom)
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Dell Canvas 27 Touch"
        MatchUSBID "2575:0204"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Surface Go
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "SurfaceGo Touch"
        MatchProduct "ELAN9038:00 04F3:261A"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Nuvision Solo 10 Draw (Supports Surface Pens)
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Nuvision Solo 10 Draw"
        MatchProduct "04F3200A:00 04F3:22F7"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

This doesn't help either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It's the `SYNA2393:00 06CB:19AC`.

You can permanently disable it by modifying the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` and comment out the whole section about `touchscreen`.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list

```
xinput
```

Then to disable device with for example id 2

```
xinput disable 2
```

Comment: Well, as explained in the text, i cant find anything that resembles touch screen shen using xinput